# How to plot a numpy array over a pcolor image in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colormap

I would like to plot a matrix as image and a vector as a line in this image.

something like that:
[image]

I manage to do the code for the matrix image, but I'm not able to make the black line (here I did just
an example in powerpoint).

this is my code so far:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator
from matplotlib import rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import numpy as np

rcParams['font.size']=35
x = np.arange(1,16,1)
y = np.arange(-50,0,1)
z =  100 * np.random.random_sample((15, 50)) 
line = np.linspace(0,100,50)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25,25))
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.1)

im = ax.pcolor(x,y,z.T,norm=LogNorm(0.1, 100),cmap= 'jet')
cbar = fig.colorbar(im,cax=cax, orientation='vertical')
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(LogLocator())  # <- Why? See above.
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('Resistividade \u03C1 [ohm.m]', rotation=270)
#ax2=ax.twinx()
#ax2.plot(line,y,'k--',linewidth=10)
ax.set_xlabel('Aquisição')
ax.set_ylabel('Profundidade [m]')
plt.savefig('mrec_1'+'.png',bbox_inches = "tight", format='png', dpi=300)  
plt.show()
```

I have tried to use the ax.twinx() but since the order of magnetude is different the values on x-axis doesn' match.
Would someone help me please?

Comment: if you want to plot a line over a pcolor plot, all you have to do is make a pcolor plot and then plot the line, you can do it all on the same axis.
of course you need x and y coordinates for your line. In your example the line goes from 0 to 100, but x only goes from 1 to 15. So there is a missmatch.

Comment: @BlueScr33n thank you for answering, in my code I wanna plot ( like I have in commented lines ax2.plot(line,y)) the line, my line has 50 elements, just like the y from the image, the problem is that the unit from the image x axis is completely different from the line, so I can't see the line.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Yes the line has a different range than the image. Do you want to use a second x axis, but on the same plot with the same y axis?

Comment: @BlueScr33n yes, I would like to have a second x axis, and that the image looks like the one I posted

Comment: use twiny instead of twinx, and while we are on it. Separate the colorbar more clearly from the plot. It looks as if the colorbar was part of the plot and not separate.

Comment: @BlueScr33n thank you for the advice, I did manage to plot the line as I wish, but not increase the space between the colorbar, the pad is not working...I have tried to increase from 0.1 to 2.0 but nothing changes cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=2)

Comment: I am not familiar with AxesDivider. Maybe you need to add 'pad' to the cbar itself. But I don't think you actually need the axes divider. You should be able to create the cbar without cax. You could then add padding to the cbar itself, like `cbar = fig.colorbar(im, orientation='vertical', pad=0.01)`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this but it depends on the kind of data you have for the black line "track". I think you can just make an array of different (x,y) coordinates for the vertices (where the line changes direction + point of origin and point of end). Basing on what I saw in the image, you can add these two lines (is an approximation)

```
coordinates=np.array([[7,0],[7,-5],[9,-5],[9,-13], [7,-13],[7,-23],[13,-23],[13,-60]])
ax.plot(coordinates[:,0], coordinates[:,1], c='k', linewidth=10)
```

where every element of coordinates is the [x,y] couple. But if you have x and y from a well log, for example, you can just use those as arrays instead of coordinates[:,0] and coordinates[:,1]

Comment: I do have the coordinates from a well log, and this is what I wanna plot over the inversion resul (the image). but when I tried to do that, the scale in the simple way (as in my code) the well log becomes only a straight line, because the x scale of the imae is not good for the well log

Answer (score 0):

As @BlueScr33n mentioned I used the twiny and works fine.